# Message "Application does not have the capability to make this API call." on API '/adcreative'

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

I'm trying to create automated Facebook ads using [Facebook Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/) and [Facebook Python Business SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/). So far I succeeded in posting new campaign and ad sets, but when I tried created the ad creatives it returned message "Application does not have the capability to make this API call.".

```
  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  POST
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/act_xxxxxx/adcreatives
  Params:  //XXX
  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
        "code": 3,
        "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxx",
        "type": "OAuthException"
      }
    }
```

My user token permission has `ads_management` and `ads_read` and the app also has `ads_reads` and `ads_management`.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you found the way to fix this?

Comment: any updates? same issue

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Same issue.....